# CastError: Cast to date failed for value date at path

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make a query in my database developed in Mongo, we have the schema Examen (or Exam) and we need to find all the exams between two dates.
My system can get both dates and make the Query with this form (im using Moment as well in order to get the correct format)

This is the query that I get from the website

```
{ "examDate": { "$gt": { "$date": "1556686800000" }, "$lt": { "$date": "1559192400000"} } }
```

when I run this query in Studio3T it works normally but in the website it has an error:

> CastError: Cast to date failed for value "{ '$date': '1559192400000'
>   }" at path "examDate" for model "Examen"

I have tried to change the '$date' format using the ISO format as well, that didn't work. And is weird that the query works normally in Studio3T but it dont works like this using the Mongo db.find() function.

```
//this is how I make the find function for my schema
Examen.find((query), (err, info_examen) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: `Error: ${err}` })
    if (!info_examen) return res.status(404).send({ message: `there is no data` })
    res.status(200).send({ info_examen })
})
```

I expect to get the result (info_examen) in order to make statistics with the data.

Comment: Try this `{ "examDate": { "$gt": new Date(1556686800000), "$lt": new Date(1559192400000) } }`

Comment: `{ "examDate": { "$gt": new Date(1556686800000) , "$lt": new Date(1559278800000) } }`
SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 24

Comment: Now this is probably somewhere else nothing with the above code.